# How Do I know if I have Android NDK on my mac android environment?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I've installed java jm and eclipse for android, checked of the packages I need are there in the Android manager.

now I read I need to install Android NDK, but before that, How do I check if it is installed in the first place and if so, what version?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not remember download the NDK, I don't think you have installed it.
The NDK downloads can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Download the zip and extract it in a location you can remember. You'll need to point to your NDK in your eclipse by adding the path of ndk-build to Window > preferences > android > NDK.

Right click on your project folder. Choose android tools -> add native support (the bottom one) and click finish. 
Now it will ask for a name for your .so file, just click ok.

Go to project -> properties -> C/C++ build -> build variables -> add
Name: NDKROOT
Path: the path you also added in your preferences to android NDK

Go to C/C++ build and uncheck Use default build path. Change the build path to ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build

And now you should be able to compile with your android NDK.

Comment: I do not get why I get down voted since it should be a help for the poster.

Comment: I am not the down voter though I agree on it. The answer to "How Do I know if I have Android NDK on my mac android environment?" is not reinstalling it.

Comment: But that is only part of this answer "If you do not remember download the NDK, I don't think you have installed it." is the main point,

Answer (score 0):

What about `locate ndk-build`, having checked that the db is up to date (`sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`)? That's what I'd do.

An alternative would be using the `find` command, as suggested by DeGoosseZ:

```
find / -name ndk-build
```

where the "/" means searching in all directories starting from the root, and "ndk-build" is the name to look for.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
command -v ndk-build
```

should show you ndk-build location if is installed

Comment: That would only find it if it were in the search path of the current shell.